# Incremental Ranges!

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, array

Your task is to, given two positive integers, \$x\$ and \$n\$, return the first \$x\$ numbers in the incremental ranges sequence.

The incremental range sequence first generates a range from one to \$n\$ inclusive. For example, if \$n\$ was \$3\$, it would generate the list \$[1,2,3]\$. It then repeatedly appends the last \$n\$ values incremented by \$1\$ to the existing list, and continues.

An input of \$n=3\$ for example:

```
n=3
1. Get range 1 to n. List: [1,2,3]
2. Get the last n values of the list. List: [1,2,3]. Last n=3 values: [1,2,3].
3. Increment the last n values by 1. List: [1,2,3]. Last n values: [2,3,4].
4. Append the last n values incremented to the list. List: [1,2,3,2,3,4]
5. Repeat steps 2-5. 2nd time repeat shown below.

2nd repeat:
2. Get the last n values of the list. List: [1,2,3,2,3,4]. Last n=3 values: [2,3,4]
3. Increment the last n values by 1. List: [1,2,3,2,3,4]. Last n values: [3,4,5].
4. Append the last n values incremented to the list. List: [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]
```

**Test cases:**

```
n,   x,   Output
1,  49,   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49]
2, 100,   [1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,22,22,23,23,24,24,25,25,26,26,27,27,28,28,29,29,30,30,31,31,32,32,33,33,34,34,35,35,36,36,37,37,38,38,39,39,40,40,41,41,42,42,43,43,44,44,45,45,46,46,47,47,48,48,49,49,50,50,51]
3,  13,   [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,5]
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n,x:[v/n+v%n+1for v in range(x)]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPp8Iqukw/T7tMNU/bMC2/SKFMITNPoSgxLz1Vo0Iz9j9IqCS1uAQkqqFhqKNgYqmpo6BhpKNgaGAAYhkDWcaamlZcnAVFmXklYMU6CupW6jCBNA0tkJgmlP8fAA)**

Comment: Also works in Python 3 with the replacement of `/` with `//`

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 33 bytes

```r
function(n,x,z=1:x-1)z%%n+z%/%n+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPp0KnytbQqkLXULNKVTVPu0pVH0ga/k/TMNQxsdTkStMw0jE0MAAxjHUMjTW5/gMA)

Ports [Jonathan Allan's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186243/67312).

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 36 bytes

```r
function(n,x)outer(1:n,0:x,"+")[1:x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPp0Izv7QktUjD0CpPx8CqQkdJW0kz2tCqIvZ/moaxjqGx5n8A)

My original solution; generates an \$n\times x\$ matrix with each column as the increments, i.e., \$1 \ldots n, 2\ldots n+1,\ldots\$, then takes the first \$x\$ entries (going down the columns).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḷd§‘
```

A dyadic Link accepting two positive integers, `x` on the left and `n` on the right, which yields a list of positive integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm0ph5Y/apjx//9/Q@P/xgA)**

#### How?

```
Ḷd§‘ - Link: x, n              e.g   13, 3
Ḷ    - lowered range (x)             [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
 d   - divmod (n)                    [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],[4,0]]
  §  - sums                          [0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4]
   ‘ - increment (vectorises)        [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,5]
```

Comment: Wait... is that divmod? Clever! And I was struggling with `p`...

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>13</s></sup> 12 bytes

```
[$[:,1++/&i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZG5TgQxEAVzvqKEEMtqD9yH55KIkIiISDdErICE/4@G8bwBqR3arqr@nm/PuytPEzuOFKblnM48v72@zJe7y3S0w@Hx/us8728@3j9/eMiRK7bnNGE4QVLp6BkYsYIZ5lhgiVWsw3pswEa84MsdxwNPvOId3uMDPhKFMGJ5MogkKtERPTEQI1lII51cfkyykh3ZkwM5bmhWysLm/2yNrvE1wsbYKBtnIxWrcEUsaHELXfQSkMOqsZlIRj5SkpXE5CY9Ga6Sm6dUZSthOUtb5pKX/5pgq6AQaqEcKqIo6qI0qtMCtallHfuLFUurWFtti9QytVAttd7Mvw)

### how

We take `x` as the left arg, `n` as the right.  Let's take `x = 8` and `n = 3` for this example:

- `+/&i.`: Transform both args by creating integer ranges `i.`, that is, the left arg becomes `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7` and the right arg becomes `0 1 2`.  Now we create an "addition table `+/` from those two:

  ```
   0 1 2
   1 2 3
   2 3 4
   3 4 5
   4 5 6
   5 6 7
   6 7 8
   7 8 9
  ```
- `1 +`: Add 1 to every element of this table:

  ```
   1 2  3
   2 3  4
   3 4  5
   4 5  6
   5 6  7
   6 7  8
   7 8  9
   8 9 10
  ```
- `[: ,`: Flatten it `,`:

  ```
   1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7 6 7 8 7 8 9 8 9 10
  ```
- `[ $`: Shape it `$` so it has the same number of elements as the original, untransformed left arg `[`, ie, `x`:

  ```
   1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4
  ```

Comment: Nice! [My 12-byte alternative](https://tio.run/##PZE7SwNBFEb7/IqDCEkwCXMfsy8QBMHKytpUYlAb/3@17uy3CHfKmTnn3J/57rK/8Tix50RhWs75wvPb68t8vbeH09Ph@v59Oc7H3efH1y8H40aOR84ThhMklY6egRErmGGOBZZYxTqsxwZsxAu@3HE88MQr3uE9PuAjUQgjlieDSKISHdETAzGShTTSyeXHJCvZkT05LDQbmi9oVso/W6NrfI2wMTbKxtlIxSpcEQta3EIXvQTksGpsJpKRj5RkJTG5SU@Gq@TmKVXZSljO0pa55OW/JtgqKIRaKIeKKIq6KI3qtEBtalnHtljRYsXaaluklqmFaql1N/8B)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 18 bytes

```perl6
{(1..*X+ ^*)[^$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNQT08rQlshTkszOk4lPrb2f3FipUKahl60YawmkDSI1VRIyy/i0jDUUTCx1NTh0jDSUTA0MACxjIEsY02d/wA)

Curried function `f(x)(n)`.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                }  # Anonymous block
      X+     # Cartesian product with addition
  1..*       # of range 1..Inf
         ^*  # and range 0..n
 (         )[^$_]  # First x elements
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L<s‰O>
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186242/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

First input is \$x\$, second input is \$n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx6b4UcMGf7v//w2NuYwB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/s5ulir6SQmJeioGQPZj5qmwRk/vexKX7UsMHf7r/Of0MuE0suIy5DAwMuYy5DYwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L       # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
        #  i.e. 13 → [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
 <      # Decrease each by 1 to the range [0, input)
        #  → [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  s‰    # Divmod each by the second input
        #  i.e. 3 → [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],[4,0]]
    O   # Sum each pair
        #  → [0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4]
     >  # And increase each by 1
        #  → [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,5]
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

---

My own initial approach was **8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:

```
LI∍εN¹÷+
```

First input is \$n\$, second input is \$x\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx/NRR@@5rX6Hdh7erv3/vzGXoTEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/s5nl4Qqi9kkJiXoqCkr2nSxiQ/ahtEpD93yfyUUfvua1@EYe3a/@v1flvyGViyWXEZWhgwGXMZWgMAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L         # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
          #  i.e. 3 → [1,2,3]
 I∍       # Extend it to the size of the second input
          #  i.e. 13 → [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
   ε      # Map each value to:
    N¹÷   #  The 0-based index integer-divided by the first input
          #   → [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]
       +  #  Add that to the value
          #   → [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,5]
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 25 bytes

```matlab
@(n,x)((1:n)'+(0:x))(1:x)
```

Anonymous function that inputs numbers `n` and `x`, and outputs a row vector.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0@nQlNDw9AqT1NdW8PAqkJTE8ip0PyfpmGsY2is@R8A)

### How it works

Consider `n=3` and `x=13`.

The code `(1:n)'` gives the column vector

```matlab
1
2
3
```

Then `(0:x)` gives the row vector

```matlab
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

The addition `(1:n)'+(0:x)` is element-wise with broadcast, and so it gives a matrix with all pairs of sums:

```matlab
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Indexing with `(1:x)` retrieves the first `x` elements of this matrix in column-major linear order (down, then across), as a row vector:

```matlab
1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6 5
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
n#x=take x$[1..n]++map(+1)(n#x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HckxDsAQFADQq/yEgRCJqm5OIgaDpIIfaQ1ur43hTe@Ob0m1roVkuhFLgkm9VgqDEC12JjRnf/HVYkbXn4wDKBiiDYBz4LU8pNnOzW6XtGF9)

This might be my favorite kind of recursion. We start with the values from 1 to n and then concatenate those same values (via self-reference) +1. then we just take the first x values.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 100 bytes

```
(<>)<>{({}[()]<(({}))((){[()](<{}>)}{}){{}{}<>(({})<>)(<>)(<>)}{}({}[()]<(<>[]({}())[()]<>)>)>)}{}{}
```

With comments and formatting:

```
# Push a zero under the other stack
(<>)<>

# x times
{
    # x - 1
    ({}[()]<

        # Let 'a' be a counter that starts at n
        # Duplicate a and NOT
        (({}))((){[()](<{}>)}{})

        # if a == 0
        {
            # Pop truthy
            {}
            <>

            # Reset n to a
            (({})<>)

            # Push 0 to each
            (<>)(<>)
        }

        # Pop falsy
        {}

        # Decrement A, add one to the other stack, and duplicate that number under this stack
        ({}[()]<
            (<>[]({}())<>)
        >)
    >)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVC9CoMwEN7zFAddLoNQcVWnzm2HbuIQraIoKv5AS8iz20ssqZEKwcv3x3fJRlF3XtmKZl0xjHkYMyYZ0HeCF3jgmxmlSpCnITO3jb0sQ1vnYi5AdE@43h6WQ5JzjsilNmEoVcwVQXt3XUIHUQRni0k7bYp7P8A8LnP1dghJSQ6gGx@cy1RReibyxmFML9rxr/4Mcw@FyCvXQnJ9LKj2S@iKpWinX0O54@2jHQKTlBjk3JC76O9IP6WXXFc/YMEH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
+þẎḣ’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9qZWxsef//K8O@4bqO4bij4oCZ////M/8xMw)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s>, 10 bytes

```
:!i:q+2G:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30ox06pQ28jdSvP/f2MuQ2MA)

-6 bytes saved thanks to Guiseppe and Luis Mendo!

Explanation:

```
:!          % Push the array [1; 2; ... n;]
  i:q       % Push the array [0 1 2 ... x - 1]
     +      % Add these two arrays with broadcasting
      2G    % Push x again
        :)  % Take the first x elements
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 34 bytes

```forth
: f 0 do i over /mod + 1+ . loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYw7DoMwFMB2TmGxIkISWCgSd6kIaSsVvaeUz/HTsNiL5Shpf7eveCvnBxFLED7IuSa6TQINrsHwFVGmkihLwodD@V1PxWMSww1TQztTl0kppsoxjGjlcdYW97gezX8)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new word definition
  0 do         \ start a loop from 0 to x-1
    i          \ put the current loop index on the stack
    over       \ copy n to the top of the stack
    /mod       \ get the quotient and remainder of dividing i by n
    + 1+       \ add them together and add 1
    .          \ output result
  loop         \ end the counted loop
;              \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 8 bytes

```
…@┅+‡t_<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//1HDModHU1q1HzUsLIm3@f/fmMvQGAA)

Does basically the same thing as the [Octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186256/67312) and [MATL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186258/67312) answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>12</s> 7 bytes

Port of [Jonathan's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186243/58974).

Takes `x` as the first input.

```
%VÄ+UzV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=JVbEK1V6Vg&input=MTMsMw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
->n,x{(0...x).map{|i|i/n+i%n+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cuT6eiWsNAT0@vQlMvN7GguiazJlM/TztTNU/bsLb2f4FCWrShjoKJZSwXiGmko2BoYABhGwPZxrH/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
n#x=take x$do j<-[1..];[j..j+n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0@5wrYkMTtVoUIlJV8hy0Y32lBPL9Y6OktPL0s7T9cw9n9uYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBUWZeiYKKgqGCsoKJJZKAEVDA0MAAScQYJGL8HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 36 bytes

```
n=>g=x=>x?[...g(--x),1+x%n+x/n|0]:[]
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7dtsLWrsI@Wk9PL11DV7dCU8dQu0I1T7tCP6/GINYqOvZ/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahpoaJpaZ2QkxegiYXqpSRpoahgQF2OWOgnDFQKkHzPwA)

Comment: Using `alert` or `print` instead of return an Array may reduce this to 34 bytes: [`n=>g=x=>x&&print(g(--x)|1+x%n+x/n)`](https://tio.run/##dclBDoMgEADAu/@o7sasldpLD/gXY4GgdiFgmjXx79gPdK6zTN8pz8nHnXL0b5M@gVdzFKsL69Fp0aPUdUyed3BAJHiqVm7cyp2xWFAIzxdWc@AcNtNtwUFDRA1WFh4Iqu//5PDLAcsF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-na`, 43 bytes

```perl
@r=map$_..$_+$F[1]-1,1..$_;say"@r[0..$_-1]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@hyDY3sUAlXk9PJV5bxS3aMFbXUMcQxLMuTqxUciiKNgBxdA1jlf7/NzRQMP6XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv25iHgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
{y#,/1_y(1+)\!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qulJZR98wvlLDUFszRrGi9n9atLG1oXHsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
⌐çYæ▄9
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a9875991dc39&i=1+49%0A2+100%0A3+13&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked & explained:

```
rmx|%+^ Full program, implicit input (n, x on stack; n in register X)
r       Range [0 .. x)
 m      Map:
  x|%     Divide & modulo x
     +    Add quotient and remainder
      ^   Add 1
          Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 10 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
⊢↑∘∊⊣,/∘⍳⌈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgmG/x91LXrUNvFRx4xHHV2Puhbr6IOYvZsf9XT8TwMqeNTbB1Hb1XxovTFIZd/U4CBnIBni4Rn831AhTcHEkssISBkaGHAZg2hjMGXEZQkkzQE)

A dyadic train. Left arg = interval (n), right arg = number of terms (x). `⎕IO←1`.

#### How it works

```apl
⊢↑∘∊⊣,/∘⍳⌈  ⍝ Left: interval n, Right: terms x
       ∘⍳⌈  ⍝ Generate range [1..max(n,x)]
            ⍝ (Too short array will complain at N-wise reduce)
    ⊣,/     ⍝ Extract length-n intervals (dyadic N-wise reduce)
  ∘∊        ⍝ Flatten and list the elements into a vector
⊢↑          ⍝ Take first x terms from the above
```

---

Porting [Jonah's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186247/78410) would be 10 bytes in Extended (traditional APL doesn't have an equivalent to J's `&`):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 10 bytes

```apl
⊣↑∘,1++\⍥⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/x91LX7UNvFRxwwdQ23tmEe9Sx/1bv6fBpR61NsHUdXVfGi9MUhN39TgIGcgGeLhGfzfxFIhTcGQy9DAAEgbcRkaAyljAA)

Uses `⎕IO←0`. If `⎕IO←1` were used, I'd need to replace `1+` with `¯1+`, costing one more byte (instead of saving two bytes).

#### How it works

```apl
⊣↑∘,1++\⍥⍳  ⍝ Left: x, Right: n
        ⍥⍳  ⍝ Create 0-based ranges for both args
      +\    ⍝ Outer product by addition (shortcut of ∘.+)
    1+      ⍝ Increment
  ∘,        ⍝ Flatten the matrix into a vector
⊣↑          ⍝ Take first x elements
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 77 bytes

```
_->In_n+In_x
x+n+0y+0z->a+Out_a+Out_" "+m+y
y+n->n
y+0n->z
z+m+a->z+n
z+0m->a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XtfOMy8@TxtIVHBVaOdpG1RqG1Tp2iVq@5eWxENIJQUl7VztSq5K7TxduzwgZQCkq7iqgIKJQIZ2HpBpkAvU8/@/EZehgQEA)

Increments and outputs a counter n times, then subtracts n-1 before repeating.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
ＮθＦＮ⊞υ⊕⎇‹ιθι§υ±θＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoMwDER3vsKjI6VDxchUdYpUIQZ@IAS3IIEpjlOVr0/D1ltO7/R0YfISNr/k7PidtE3rQIK7aarnJoD/ozHQpThhsuA4CK3ESiP2JOzlwAfFiLOF3VgodVPHI31Pu6WXVyqnZ5qqk5kV7z4qpsI513Ct8@Wz/AA) Link is to verbose version of code. I had dreams of seeding the list with a zero-indexed range and then slicing it off again but that was actually 2 bytes longer. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                  Input `n` into variable
   Ｎ                Input `x`
  Ｆ                 Loop over implicit range
         ι          Current index
        ‹           Less than
          θ         Variable `n`
       ⎇   ι        Then current index else
               θ    Variable `n`
              ±     Negated
            §υ      Cyclically indexed into list
      ⊕             Incremented
    ⊞υ              Pushed to list
                Ｉυ  Cast list to string for implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, <s>29 23</s> 16 bytes

```
 x↑,1+(⍳x←⎕)∘.+⍳⎕
```

Index origin = 0 and prompts for n and x

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tf8Wjtok6htoaj3o3A5kTgLKajzpm6GkD@UD2f6Ca/2lchlwmllxpXEZchgYGQNqYy9AYAA)

Answer (score 0):

## **JS, 54 bytes**

```
f=(n,x)=>Array.from(Array(x),(_,i)=>i+1-(i/n|0)*(n-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoAgEEDR68yUmrZqY9BJQiTDMA0NMejuJu0@7x8qq6SjvW6ap1qNBE8KynmJUT3MxHDCn1CQwEpsW7YXFOzgX44deCoQqw4@BbcxF3YwMBLBedP6AQ)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) As this isn't a recursive function, you don't need to count the `f=`. You can save one byte by currying the parameters (`n=>x=>`) and another by spreading & mapping the array (`[...Array(x)].map()`).

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>49</strike> 44 bytes

Using recursion to save some bytes.

```c
f(n,x){x&&printf("%d ",x%n+x/n+1,f(n,--x));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NCoMwEIX3nmIIKIlOaK3dtKE3cRMipkI7FbU2IF69aVJxM28@eD9GWmO8bzmhE4vLsn7oaGo5Sxtg6FIq3IGKEqNBSieEWv386hqwPPiAEKI4AQvsSbqlDYIL91pTPTGMLicUbCMK@vc0csbCtyZJjD91R/86PViDYO56gDwPMIfeBCCMlQjni1AbnBDK43GnKlAVYPVf0z60Hb38/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 39 bytes

```perl
say 1+int($_/$F[1])+$_%$F[1]for 0..$_-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLBUDszr0RDJV5fxS3aMFZTWyVeFcxKyy9SMNDTU4nXNfz/39BYwZjLxFLBkMvQwEDB6F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/uol5AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 48 bytes

```
procedure f(x,n)
write((0to n)+(1to x))\n&\z
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNo0InT5OrvCizJFVDw6AkXyFPU1vDEEhXaGrG5KnFVHGl5qUgachNzMzT0ORSAII0DWMdQ2NNsAIA)

Answer (score 0):

## C(clang), 843 bytes

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        int x,n;
        if (argc == 3 && (n = atoi(argv[1])) > 0 && (x = atoi(argv[2])) > 0){ 
                int* ranges = calloc(x, sizeof *ranges);
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                        if (i < n){ 
                                ranges[i] = i+1;
                        }   
                        else {
                                ranges[i] = ranges[i-n] + 1;
                        }   
                }   
        printf("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < x - 1; j++){
                printf("%d",ranges[j]);
                printf(",");
        }   
        printf("%d",ranges[x - 1]);
        printf("]\n");
        free(ranges);
        }   
        else {
                printf("enter a number greater than 0 for n and x\n");
        }   
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This challenge is tagged [code-golf], which means you have to complete the challenge in as few as possible bytes/characters. You can remove loads of whitespaces, and change variable names to single characters in your code (the `argc`, `argv` and `ranges`). Also, no need to add any warning messages.. You can assume the input is valid, unless the challenge says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 41 bytes

```cs
x=>n=>new int[x].Select((_,a)=>a/n+a%n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXogNneLrmleamFiUm5aSC@HZ2dgppCrYK/yts7fKAKLVcASgaXRGrF5yak5pcoqERr5OoaWuXqJ@nnaiap22o@d@aK7wosyTVJzMvVaO4pCgzL13PKz8zT0NJR0knTcPEUlPDUFNTE78qQwMDTQ0jwsqMNTWMQar@AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 55 bytes

```
: f ( a b -- c ) [0,b) [ over /mod + 1 + . ] with map ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDoIwFEV3v@KOEgUlbGV0ICyEhDgZh1IeSpS2Pp4av742DOcMJ7l31EYch3NXN5XCg9jSE7OW@6qMtb3RAs8k8vM8WcFCrzdZE2u5qRuFtj1VQWHEFho90hQGCS7HfR8N9yHGYXYDdsgjGa74Tuu9RxkK5EWcDuw8wh8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 34 bytes

```julia
f(n,x)=[v÷n+v%n+1 for v in 0:x-1]
```

Ports [Jonathan Allan's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186243/67312).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jT6dC0za67PD2PO0y1TxtQ4W0/CKFMoXMPAUDqwpdw9j/DsUZ@eUKaRqGOiaWmlwwnpGOoYEBgmusY2is@R8A)

Comment: [25](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/Py@mwtbAqkLXUEGvxq5M167s8PY87TLVPG3D/w7FGfnlCoYxJpZcEKZRjKGBAZRtHGNo/B8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 50 bytes

Port of Jonathan Allan's answer.

```
method(n,x,Range 0 to(x-1)map(v,(v/n)floor+v%n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/X5SYl56qYGWrEPM/N7UkIz9FI0@nQicILGqgUJKvUaFrqJmbWKBRpqNRpp@nmZaTn1@kXaaap22oqQnRrWGoo2BiqamgUFCUmVeSk8cFETXSUTA0MNBEEzUGihoj1P4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
↑Σ¡m→ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9odXNr///ihpHOo8KhbeKGkuG4o////zP/MTM)

```
↑Σ¡m→ḣ
     ḣ  Make a range [1, n]
  ¡     Make an infinite list of ranges by repeatedly
   m→   incrementing each element in that range
 Σ      Flatten that into a 1-D list
↑       Take the first x elements of that
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```factor
[ iota swap '[ _ /mod + 1 + ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoMwEAbgPU/xbx2EirjZBxCXLtJJRI70RGlM4uWk@PTR4Ru/mawGyZ@@e7cNEu8He8sJPxbPDrOc2EgXRGHVM8rqFS9jalS1yQPWoIT0p4jHgAnlFr4oUN3G@0WM2ZJzeOYL)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ʁ$vḋṠ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgSR24biL4bmg4oC6IiwiIiwiMTNcbjMiXQ==)

Port of Jelly.

```
ʁ$vḋṠ›
ʁ       # Range [0, first input)
 $      # Swap so the second input is at the top
  vḋ    # For each in the range, divmod by that
    Ṡ   # Sum each
     ›  # Increment
```